# Expanding preview (calcHeight : function)

Tags: javascript, function, preview

I'm building [a website](http://christinaibsenmeyer.dk/hn2/) over [this tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/).

I'm trying to figure out how to add an auto height based on the content’s height. It was originally locked to the windows size but I want it to expand further down.

Line 455 of the original code:

```
        calcHeight : function() {

        var heightPreview = winsize.height - this.$item.data( 'height' ) - marginExpanded,
            itemHeight = winsize.height;

        if( heightPreview < settings.minHeight ) {
            heightPreview = settings.minHeight;
            itemHeight = settings.minHeight + this.$item.data( 'height' ) + marginExpanded;
        }

        this.height = heightPreview;
        this.itemHeight = itemHeight;

    },
```

My solution that works 50% of the time (works pretty good localy?!):

```
        calcHeight : function() {
        var lol = this.$fullimage[0].getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
        var oImage = new Image();

        oImage.onload = function(){
            this.height// width of loaded image
        }

        oImage.src = lol.src;
        this.height = oImage.height;
        this.itemHeight = oImage.height+650;
    },
    setHeights : function() {

        var self = this,
            onEndFn = function() {
                if( support ) {
                    self.$item.off( transEndEventName );
                }
                self.$item.addClass( 'og-expanded' );
            };
```

Comment: Have you tried using $(document).height()?

Comment: Hi Howard, Thanks for your answer. I have already tried that.

Comment: No problem, since there's no answers yet, I'll take a look at it today and see what I can come up with for you :)

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on what you're trying to accomplish with this?  I see the tutorial that you reference, but I'm not sure how you're trying to integrate that, or what this has to do with the overall content height of the document.  Any additional details will help me understand what your goal is, then we can work toward the solution.  Thanks

Comment: What I want to achieve is a webgallery with big images (from different stories). When you want to see more images from 1 story you click and the whole story will expand. That means I cannot just lock the height of the preview because the different stories have different heights (To make this work I merge together all the images from the stories to 1 very high image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.  I think this will work for what you are trying to accomplish.  Basically, no matter how long the text, the div height will either be the height of the content, or the height of the first image, whichever is bigger.  Then when clicking the div, it will load the additional images.  After the images are loaded, if you click the div again, then it shrinks back down to its original size.

Check it out and let me know if any tweaks are needed.

*Note:  this looks better in a browser window, but works in jsfiddle.*

### http://jsfiddle.net/fLPM5/1/

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            .story {
                width:75%;
                padding:5px;
                margin:5px;
                cursor:pointer;
                border:1px solid black;
            }
            .text{
                padding:5px;
                margin:5px;
                width:20%;
            }
            .images{
                float:right;
                padding:5px;
                margin:5px;
                width:70%;
            }
            img{
                padding:5px;
                margin:5px;
                width:95%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="story" id="story1">
            <div class="images">
                <img src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg" />
                <img src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/2.jpg" />
                <img src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/3.jpg" />
                <img src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="text">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit fusce vel sapien elit in malesuada semper mi, id sollicitudin urna fermentum ut fusce varius nisl ac ipsum gravida vel pretium tellus tincidunt integer eu augue augue nunc elit dolor, luctus placerat scelerisque euismod, iaculis eu lacus nunc mi elit, vehicula ut.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit fusce vel sapien elit in malesuada semper mi, id sollicitudin urna fermentum ut fusce varius nisl ac ipsum gravida vel pretium tellus tincidunt integer eu augue augue nunc elit dolor, luctus placerat scelerisque euismod, iaculis eu 100% Original Work created by Howard Renollet for StackOverflow.com http:// stackoverflow.com /questions /19916419 /expanding-preview-calcheight-function/ ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit fusce vel sapien elit in malesuada semper mi, id sollicitudin urna fermentum ut fusce varius nisl ac ipsum gravida vel pretium tellus tincidunt integer eu augue augue nunc elit dolor, luctus placerat scelerisque euismod, iaculis eu lacus nunc mi elit, vehicula ut.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit fusce vel sapien elit in malesuada ut fusce varius nisl ac ipsum gravida vel pretium tellus tincidunt integer eu augue augue nunc elit dolor, luctus placerat scelerisque euismod, iaculis eu lacus nunc mi elit, vehicula ut.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="story" id="story2">
            <div class="images">
                <img src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg" />
                <img src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/2.jpg" />
                <img src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/3.jpg" />
                <img src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="text">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit fusce vel sapien elit in malesuada semper mi, id sollicitudin urna fermentum ut fusce varius nisl ac ipsum gravida vel pretium tellus.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="story" id="story3">
            <div class="images">
                <img src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg" />
                <img src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/2.jpg" />
                <img src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/3.jpg" />
                <img src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="text">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit fusce vel sapien elit in malesuada semper.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            (function () {
                //Get each story box
                $(".story").each(function () {

                    //for each .images box
                    $(this).children(".images").each(function () {
                        //hide all of the images
                        $(this).children("img").hide();
                    });

                    //show the first image
                    $(this).children(".images").children("img:first").show();

                    //get the text height
                    var textHeight = $(this).children(".text").height();

                    //get the image height
                    var imgHeight = $(this).children(".images:first-child").height();

                    //define originalHeight
                    var originalHeight;

                    //Which one is bigger?
                    if (textHeight >= imgHeight) {
                        //If the text height is larger
                        //set the story box height to the text height
                        $(this).height(textHeight);
                        //set originalHeight
                        originalHeight = textHeight;

                    }
                    else if (imgHeight > textHeight) {
                        //if the image height is larger
                        //set the story box height to the image height
                        $(this).height(imgHeight);
                        //set originalHeight
                        originalHeight = imgHeight;
                    };

                    //when clicking the div
                    $(this).click(function () {

                        //if this height is less than the image max height
                        if ($(this).height() <= originalHeight) {

                            //show the images
                            $(this).children(".images").children("img").show();

                            //set this height to the image max height
                            $(this).height($(this).children(".images").height());
                        }
                        else {
                            //for each .images box
                            $(this).children(".images").each(function () {

                                //hide all of the images
                                $(this).children("img").hide();
                            })

                            //show the first image
                            $(this).children(".images").children("img:first").show();

                            //set the text height
                            var textHeight = $(this).children(".text").height();

                            //set the image height
                            var imgHeight = $(this).children(".images:first-child").height();

                            //Which one is bigger?
                            if (textHeight >= imgHeight) {
                                //If the text height is larger

                                //set the story box height to the text height
                                $(this).height(textHeight);
                            }
                            else if (imgHeight > textHeight) {
                                //if the image height is larger

                                //set the story box height to the image height
                                $(this).height(imgHeight);
                            };
                        };
                    });
                });
            })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Заменить этим:

calcHeight : function() {

```
        var heightPreview = $('.og-details p').height() + this.$item.data( 'height' ) + marginExpanded,
            itemHeight = heightPreview;

        if( heightPreview < settings.minHeight ) {
            heightPreview = settings.minHeight;
            itemHeight = settings.minHeight + this.$item.data( 'height' ) + marginExpanded;

        }

        this.height = heightPreview;
        this.itemHeight = itemHeight + this.$item.data( 'height' ) + marginExpanded ;

    },
```

Comment: Explain your code, Code only answers are not appreciated.