# Grid with Expanding Preview - Calculate Height Based on Content Height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am using the functionality from the "[Thumbnail Grid with Expanding Preview](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview)" tutorial (like everyone else it would seem O_o) I have it all working pretty much the way I want, except that instead of div.og-expanded expanding to the full height of the page, I'd like div.og-expanded to expand only to the size of the content within the container instead.

I'm using the latest code from [Github](https://github.com/codrops/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview).

The height of div.og-expanded seems to be controlled by calcHeight : function in grid.js

```
        calcHeight : function() {

        var heightPreview = winsize.height - this.$item.data( 'height' ) - marginExpanded,
            itemHeight = winsize.height;

        if( heightPreview < settings.minHeight ) {
            heightPreview = settings.minHeight;
            itemHeight = settings.minHeight + this.$item.data( 'height' ) + marginExpanded;
        }

        this.height = heightPreview;
        this.itemHeight = itemHeight;

    },
    setHeights : function() {

        var self = this,
            onEndFn = function() {
                if( support ) {
                    self.$item.off( transEndEventName );
                }
                self.$item.addClass( 'og-expanded' );
            };

        this.calcHeight();
        this.$previewEl.css( 'height', this.height );
        this.$item.css( 'height', this.itemHeight ).on( transEndEventName, onEndFn );

        if( !support ) {
            onEndFn.call();
        }

    },
```

As I said, instead of using the window size to get the height, I'd like to base it off of the content height of div.og-expander-inner. I saw a similar question "[Expanding preview (calcHeight : function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916419/expanding-preview-calcheight-function)" The solution calculated the height based on the content of (what is essentially) div.og-fullimg or div.og-details whichever is taller. This is a decent solution as it took the responsiveness of the content into consideration, which is important to me. Unfortunately, I couldn't sort out how to apply this solution to the original source code.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.